# Laravel get column name using child table with eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to fetch the data from profile table using a child table of other parent table.

Here is the tables

Profile table

```
id
profile_name
```

Transaction table

```
id
transaction_name
```

Sub transaction table

```
id
transaction_id
profile_id
```

Now i want to get the profile name from transaction model using eager loading . i tried has one Though  relationship in transaction model but returning null

Here is my relationship in Transaction model

```
public function profileName()
    {
         return $this->hasOneThrough(
            Profiler::class,
            SubTransaction::class,
            'profile_id',
            'id',
            'id',
            'transaction_id',
         );
    }
```

Here is where i am trying to fetch from transaction controller

```
$options = Transaction::with([
            'profileName:id,profile_name as profileName',
        ])
        ->get();
```

Comment: You should be using a many to many relation... if you have a table that has `model1_id` and `model2_id` columns and that is the relation, then you should be using `belongsToMany` not `hasOneThrough`. Can you explain why `profile_id` is in `sub transaction` table and not in `transaction` table ? What is the idea of having `sub transaction` table ?

Comment: The idea of using sub transaction is because some transaction does not have profile id . so i have created a table to store profile id of those transactions. Each transaction has just one profile id so do you think it will be many to many ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns null because I think you have a little problem about matching between foreign keys and local keys. You could try the following code:

```
     return $this->hasOneThrough(
        Profiler::class, //Final model we wish to access
        SubTransaction::class, //The name of the intermediate model
        'transaction_id', //Foreign key on sub_transaction table
        'id', //Foreign key on profile table
        'id', //Local key on transaction table
        'profile_id', //Local key on sub_transaction table
     );
```

If you have any problem, tell me.